# How to prevent subdomains from redirecting to https - htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to work out how to redirect all http instances to https:// though excluding the subdomain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example.co [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.co/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

For example, **domain.example.co** should be left as it is and not redirected to `https://`.

**example.co** or **example.co/sub/sub** should be redirected to `https://`

I have tried changing the RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.co/$1 [R,L]
```

This leaves subdomains as they are but has no effect on subdirectories under example.co - i.e. example.co/sub/sub.

How could I redirect from http to https but exclude all subdomains?

**Note**

I also have a rewrite rule which points subdomains to their directories without changing the URL:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.co/%1/$1 [P]
```

`sub.example.co` will displays `example.co/sub` but the URL will not change

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Or This :

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Note: Replace sub with subdomain and domain with domain name

Enjoy it ;-)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response but this would only work for `sub.domain.com` right? How can I get this to work for all subdomains

Comment: Thank you, however `sub.domain.com` just gets redirected to `domain.com/sub` so ends up with https. Perhaps this has something to do with the other rewrite rule that I have (check the edited version) but I am not quite sure

Comment: try this code: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, subdomains are still redirected to `example.com/subdomain` rather than remaining as `subdomain.example.com` - This seems to work without the provided code but then https doesn't work on the domain

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in the sub-domains folder? (public_html/<subdomain>/.htaccess)
Because the code that you have, at various sites tested.
But surely this code in the .htaccess file in the folder there is a sub-domain.
Again, if you have not received an answer.
You can tell the system (CMS) you are using, so that I can help you be more.
and try this code: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]`

Comment: Thanks though there's only one htaccess file and the code provided also seems to redirect all subdomains to their directories whilst having the URL remain the same. I'm also not using a CMS

Answer (score 0):

Try below I am assuming you are not using www appended to host.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.co/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.co [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://example.co/%1/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://example.co/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this seems to redirect all subdomains to `example.co/subdomain` and so as a result just adds a https at the end. Subdomains should remain as they are (Also see the **Note** at the end of the question detail)

Comment: I think this rule is working as it should be but you have to make sure your other rule is working, because sometime when using proxy rule it redirects when it is not working correctly. you can check here http://htaccess.mwl.be/

Comment: If I remove the http to https rewrite rule, then it seems to work correctly as `subdomain.example.co` remains as it is without being redirected

Comment: Thank you but this causes an internal server error for some reason